# Comparing densities of different gapped primes (twin, cousin, sexy...)

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem, prime-gaps

In this experiment, I have checked how many times different gapped primes occur out of the first 10000, 100000, 1000000 first primes.

Please view the following as ($X$:$Y$) where $X$ represents the gap and $Y$ represents how many times it occurs.

Out of first 1000000 primes:

**2:** 40405
**4:** 40233
**6:** 68311
**8:** 28746
**10:** 36766
**12:** 44113
**14:** 23569
**16:** 16658
**18:** 29065
**20:** 14409
**22:** 12833
**24:** 17680
**26:** 7979
**28:** 8493
**30:** 13773
**32:** 4048
**34:** 4263
**36:** 6344
**38:** 2749
**40:** 3313
**42:** 4424
**44:** 1717
**46:** 1387
**48:** 2235

Out of first 100000 primes:

**2:** 10251
**4:** 10213
**6:** 15989
**8:** 7067
**10:** 8873
**12:** 10158
**14:** 5353
**16:** 3661
**18:** 6304
**20:** 3043
**22:** 2826
**24:** 3538
**26:** 1543
**28:** 1631
**30:** 2114
**32:** 742
**34:** 756
**36:** 1032
**38:** 455
**40:** 563
**42:** 661
**44:** 250
**46:** 219
**48:** 290

Out of first 10000 primes:

**2:** 1271
**4:** 1263
**6:** 2012
**8:** 801
**10:** 953
**12:** 1008
**14:** 512
**16:** 353
**18:** 537
**20:** 249
**22:** 235
**24:** ///22///
**26:** 91
**28:** 102
**30:** 154
**32:** 35
**34:** 36
**36:** 55
**38:** 20
**40:** 28
**42:** ///20///
**44:** 5
**46:** 6
**48:** ///3///

You will notice the following:

- A peak occurs in almost all $X \mod 6 =0$ compared to the prior 2. The only exceptions are in the first first 10000 primes and only in $X=24$, $X=42$ and $X=48$
- There are always more shorter gaps than longer gaps

My question is broken into 3 parts:

A) Is it fair to assume that probably there are more shorter gaps than longer gaps?

B) Is it fair to assume that probably there are more $X \mod 6=0$ gaps than any other gaps?

C) If B) is assumed to be fair, is it fair to assume that SEXY primes (primes with a gap of 6) are the most popular gap between primes?

Comment: The Hardy–Littlewood prime tuples conjecture (see, for example, this post on Tao's blog for the statement: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/the-prime-tuples-conjecture-sieve-theory-and-the-work-of-goldston-pintz-yildirim-motohashi-pintz-and-zhang/) gives conjectural asymptotic densities for all prime tuples, and fixed gaps between primes are a special case. Does this address some of your questions?

Comment: It's generally believed that the most common gap between consecutive primes increases without bound the farther out you go – it's just that you have to go out pretty far (much farther than a mere million primes) to see it happen.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson The article explains A) and C) but there is not much mentioning in regards to the other $X \ mod 6 = 0$ ‘s overall increase

Comment: Asked as a variant on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014327/is-it-fair-to-assume-that-probably-eventually-there-will-always-be-more-of-x-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Odlyzko, Michael Rubinstein, and Marek Wolf, Jumping champions, Experimental Mathematics 8 (1999), 107–118 suggest that somewhere around $x=1.7427\times10^{35}$, the most common gap between consecutive primes less than $x$ switches from $6$ to $30$.

See The Most Common Prime Gaps, posted by John Baez, at https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2016/03/the_most_common_prime_gaps.html

Comment: The article explains A) and C) but there is not much mentioning in regards to the other $X \mod 6 = 0$ ‘s overall increases (asked in B))

Comment: If $p>3$ is prime and $x\equiv0\bmod6$ then $p+x$ is guaranteed not to be divisible by three which makes it more likely to be prime than $p+y$ for $y$ close to $x$ but not a multiple of six. I'd guess that for large $p$ a gap of six is more common than four or eight, $12$ is more common than $10$ or $14$, $18$ is more common than $16$ or $20$, and so on. There might be an exception for a gap of $x\not\equiv0\bmod6$ if $x$ is divisible by enough small primes, if $\sum_{p\mid x}p^{-1}>1/3$.

Comment: Many gratitudes for commenting back. And i just wanted to updated you that I have started a variant question here (while incorporating your answers) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014327/is-it-fair-to-assume-that-probably-eventually-there-will-always-be-more-of-x-m  which seems to be more of a suitable forum